# Using PCR to add the overhangs to gBlocks for NEB HiFi

Tags: pcr, cloning, synthetic-biology

Does adding the overhangs to gBlocks for NEB Hifi using PCR pose a big problem? The [IDT website](https://go.idtdna.com/iGEM-2020-FAQ.html) suggests that one should design the gBlocks with the overhangs. However, if I did not do this, will it be a problem?

Edit: I intent to use Q5 High-Fidelity Polymerase and the gBlocks range from 500-2200 bp in size. It's not necessary for the exact sequence to be present.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your question to provide more details such as: the error rate of the polymerase you intend to use, the size of the gBlock, and how critical it is to you that the exact sequence be present for your application. You may also benefit from taking the [tour] and consulting the [help] starting with [ask]. This will familiarize you with how this site works and what the expectations are for questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the overhangs with PCR, then gel purify or PCR purify. I don't think it will pose a big problem as I've done it before and all of the colonies I screened were correct.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. In particular, you are ignoring a potentially significant problem with this approach — the error rate of the DNA polymerase being used. I've posted a comment to the OP asking them to give us more detail, but please also edit your answer to be more complete. Please see the [tour] and [help] starting with [answer] questions effectively for details about site expectations. Thanks!

Comment: Error rate here of Q5 polymerase is 5.3 x 10^-7 [1].  One would have to be remarkably unlucky for error to propagate into your final clone.  [1]  Paulo Cseri Ricardo, Elaine Françoso & Maria Cristina Arias (2020) Fidelity of DNA polymerases in the detection of intraindividual variation of mitochondrial DNA, Mitochondrial DNA Part B, 5:1, 108-112, DOI: 10.1080/23802359.2019.1697188